# NGINX subdirectory with rewrite and proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite, proxypass

I want the proxy to be able to return everything needed to correctly return what is needed to view `http://joelmccune.com` through an NGINX proxy location, `http://nginx/joel`. What I have so far works fine for the root of the site, but when the root attempts to load resources such as css files, from subdirectories, the client cannot resolve them.

For instance, in the root of the site, the index.html file contains a line to load an external css file.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/screen.css?v=4a6391e0a5" />`

This file is located at...

`http://joelmccune.com/assets/css/screen.css?v=4a6391e0a5`

...and I want the proxy to recognize the pattern. To return the resource through the URL...

`http://nginx/joel/assets/css/screen.css?v=4a6391e0a5`

Right now it fails, a 404 error, since it is trying to load from...

`http://nginx/assets/css/screen.css?v=4a6391e0a5`

Obviously, there are multiple subdirectories, and I want to be able to add more proxy locations as well, so I am trying to figure out how to create a universal pattern to accomplish this.

Here is the config file I am using...

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    # if the request is a referall from //nginx/joel
    if ($http_referrer ~* nginx/joel) {

        # rewrite the request to be prefixed with //nginx/joel
        rewrite ^/?(.*)$ http://nginx/joel/$2 last;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    # proxy any requests to /joel to http://joelmccune.com
    location /joel {
        proxy_pass http://joelmccune.com/;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

Here are the response headers from the initial request to the root.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.0
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 20:56:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=db5b717394ddd2681553aed3a5a6d354b1495573008; expires=Wed, 23-May-18 20:56:48 GMT; path=/; domain=.joelmccune.com; HttpOnly
Status: 200 OK
x-powered-by: Express
cache-control: public, max-age=0
vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Ghost-Cache-Status: From Cache
CF-RAY: 363aec8a00b479ff-SEA
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Here are the request headers to retrieve the example css resource. Looking at the referer is where I got the idea to try and isolate subsequent resource requests with rewrite...an idea currently not working.

```
GET /assets/css/screen.css?v=4a6391e0a5 HTTP/1.1
Host: nginx
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
DNT: 1
Referer: http://nginx/joel/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

And here are the response headers from my example resource, the css file...obviously not providing much insight except to confirm it is not loading.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.12.0
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 20:56:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 571
Connection: keep-alive
```

Thank you in advance for any insight you can offer. This has been vexing me for the better part of a couple days now.

Note: To test, and learn how this all works, I am using Vagrant + VirtualBox + Ubuntu + NGINX with my local hosts file modified to point all requests to `http://nginx` to the virtual machine IP address. This should explain the URL structures detailed above.

Comment: Why are you trying to redirect requests with a specific referrer? That's unusual. Your problem and question are rather long winded and unclear. For example you've said "assets/css/screen.css?v=4a6391e0a5 is attempting to resolve to ", but that isn't a well formed URL so it's ambiguous. You could also use curl showing response headers to demonstrate what's happening rather than describing it. Finally, please edit your question rather than trying to add information in comments.

Comment: @Tim, after over 48 hours of messing with this, I'm trying anything I can think of. I'm perfectly open to entertaining any _constructive_ suggestions as to how to proceed. Yes, I edited to try and clarify. No, I am not skilled at curl, so this is why I am not using it. Yes, I am learning. This is why I am asking this question.

Comment: Posting diagnostic information is important if you want help. [Curl instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060098/getting-only-response-header-from-http-post-using-curl).

Comment: The headers suggest you're running on CloudFlare, and you have something called Ghost Cache installed. That could be relevant, if the request doesn't make it to Nginx. This is why access logs can be useful. It's better to show the curl command line, because that would tell us if you've added say a referrer header. I guess the css is being proxied through to the joelmccune.com website, show the access logs from the proxied server along with the matching nginx access logs and the curl would make it easier to understand what's going on. You have to try to make it easy for people to help you.